# Changes in thebibliography environment

Tags: bibliographies

I am trying to make two changes in `thebibliography` environment. In particular, I need two things:

1) I need the style of the heading "References" to be different from the `\section` environment. In particular, I need the references to appear just below the heading, without a vertical space.

2) I need the references to be aligned as the main text. Now, I don't know why the references appear like they are indented.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm,bindingoffset=10mm]{geometry}
\linespread{1}
\setlength\parindent{1.25cm}
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\small}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\setlength\footnotemargin{1.25cm}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Standard diachritics in Romance languages (accents, umlauts)
\usepackage{times} %Uses Times New Roman font
\usepackage{tikz}
%\noautomath
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[all,defaultlines=2]{nowidow}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{}
\makeatother


\usepackage[tiny]{titlesec}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\itshape}
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{2\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{0\baselineskip}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\itshape}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}
{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{0\baselineskip}




\let\OLDthebibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand\thebibliography[1]{
  \OLDthebibliography{#1}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt plus 0.3ex}
}


\makeatletter
% patch \maketitle so that it doesn't center
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{center}{flushleft}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{center}{flushleft}{}{}
% patch \maketitle so that the font size for the title is normal
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\LARGE}{\normalsize}{}{}

\def\maketitle{{%
        \renewenvironment{tabular}[2][]
        {\begin{flushleft}}
            {\end{flushleft}}
        \AB@maketitle}}
\makeatother

\def\bibindent{3em}
\makeatletter
\let\old@biblabel\@biblabel
\def\@biblabel#1{\old@biblabel{#1}\kern\bibindent}
\let\old@bibitem\bibitem
\def\bibitem#1{\old@bibitem{#1}\leavevmode\kern-\bibindent}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}



\begin{document}

    \section{First section}
\lipsum[3]

    \subsection{Subsection}
 \lipsum[3]

 \subsection{Subsubsection}
 \lipsum[3]

\begin{thebibliography}{57}

\bibitem{key-1}Adger, David. 2003. \emph{Core Syntax. A minimalist
Approach}. Oxford University Press, New York.
\bibitem{key-16}Alberdi, Xabier. 1994. \emph{Euskararen tratamenduak: erabilera. }EHU-UPV.
\bibitem{key-2}Albizu, Pablo. 1991. ``Sobre la existencia del Movimiento
Largo de N\'{u}cleos en Euskera." Manuscript, Instituto Universitario
Ortega y Gasset, Madrid.



\end{thebibliography}







\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add negative `vspace` in the  end of new `thebibliography` to reduce this spacing. One work around to solve the second issue is to set `\itemindent` negative value so that items will move left. Something like this:

```
\let\OLDthebibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand\thebibliography[1]{
  \OLDthebibliography{#1}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt plus 0.3ex}
  \setlength{\itemindent}{-1ex}
   \vspace{-2ex}
}
```

[image]

Comment: It works wonders! Thank you very much. Any thoughts about the first problem?

Comment: @crealp I didn't quite understand the first part. *"just below the heading, without a horizontal space."* Did you mean vertical space?

Comment: Yes! Without a vertical space. Sorry (I will edit the question). I want the title of the bibliography to have a different style from the first level heading "\section". I guess that the problem is that "thebibliography" environment issues the  style of the \section environment, and I don't know if I can change that.

Comment: @crealp see the updated version of answer